# Using otf files in the TEXMF tree with lualatex

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I'm trying to use an otf file that is in the TEXMF tree, but another file with the same name is used instead.

I run lualatex from a locally installed TexLive 2019 on this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont [
  ItalicFont = LinLibertine_RI.otf,
  BoldFont = LinLibertine_RB.otf,
  ]{LinLibertine_R.otf}

\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

and get the output

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./whichfont.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.076 seconds
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
No file whichfont.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./whichfont.aux))
 410 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 5 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 5 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:15,3:4,4:1,5:22,6:1,7:16,9:7
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_R.o
tf>
Output written on whichfont.pdf (1 page, 2910 bytes).
Transcript written on whichfont.log.
```

As you can see files that are part of the Texlive 2019 installation are used, except that the file `LinLibertine_R.otf` is from another location. I would like to instead use the version that is in `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine` (or rather the version that is in the TEXMF tree I use when TeXing the file).

I though this would do it:

```
$ luaotfload-tool --cache=erase
$ luaotfload-tool --update --prefer-texmf
```

but even after repeating lualatex after those commands it uses the same otf file. What can I do? (A `kpsewhich LinLibertine_R.otf` finds `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_R.otf` as expected.)

I thought a workaround could be to use an explicit path, but actually, when adding

```
Path = /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/
```

it still chooses the other file! (It matters what path I write though, because it complains it can't find the file if I give another directory!)

Comment: It is not. a good idea to install `texlive` in an own directory and also a `texlive` with the package manager of your Linux distribution. You should delete the files installed by the package manager.

Comment: Does setting an explicit  `Path` option in the `\setmainfont` directive help?

Comment: @Mico I mention that as a possible workaround that didn't work at the end. (But even if it did work it's not a real solution anyway.)

Comment: What does your log-file say about the cache path? (look for "Lookup cache loaded from ...").

Comment: The output `texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_R.otf` shows that the fonts used are from the texlive texmf tree.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Aha, this time it was in my own .texlive2019, and removing that I now get the result I wanted. I should add that there was no really old info there though. On that box I had a freshly installed texlive 2019 just to do this example with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to prefer fonts in the texmf directory to system fonts, you can set the "`location_precedence`" of luaotfload:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
  fonts.names.set_location_precedence{
    "local", "texmf", "system" % The default is "local", "system", "texmf"
  }
}

\setmainfont [
  ItalicFont = LinLibertine_RI.otf,
  BoldFont = LinLibertine_RB.otf,
  ]{LinLibertine_R.otf}

\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

This still uses luaotfload's database to find the font. The font loading system also allows to load a font as `kpse:the_filname.otf` to explicitly request the use of kpse, but this isn't exposed through fontspec.

Comment: I have been just considering if we could add an option to luaotfload.conf to set the order. But beside this: is `/usr/share/texlive` a "system" folder in this sense on linux?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That depends on how you set it in the fontconfig configuration files, but if it isn't the font wouldn't be found there in the first place.

Comment: This gives me an error "[\directlua]:1: '}' expected near <eof>." What's wrong?

Comment: @pst That's fixed now. I used the wrong comment marker. If `--` is used inside `\directlua`, the whole remaining `\directlua` argument is ignored, in this case including the `}`.